# Use favicon from other site?

Tags: favicon

If I link to a favicon in my head from another domain will it work ok? I want to use the same favicon as an existing site, and my new site may end up being a different domain altogether or a sub domain of the existing one. 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put this in the head tag:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="your url here">
```

It'll work fine, but leeching (stealing bandwidth from another server) isn't cool. Host it on your own server or ask the webmaster for permission.

Comment: I believe that might be the case when you want to use a CDN for all your frontend assets including the favicon with a different domain.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you may do this, favicon is treated just as any other HTTP resources on page, so it can be external.